# Is it possible - Drupal Plugins to Java Web application

Tags: java, drupal, web-applications

This may sound really stupid, but I want to know if it is possible to convert Drupal plugins to java web application? Is there some sort of converter or connector or probably a way to achieve this?

We all know that Drupal has largest number of plugins available. I was thinking whether it is technically feasible for a drupal plugin to go through some process and come out as Java web application. Sounds silly but would be really interested if this can be achieved. The ideal scenario would be for me to have them as plugins in my java portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Drupal plugins rely on the Drupal hook system and its API, which you would have to replicate in Java. Given the complexity of Drupal's internals, that alone would likely be prohibitively difficult. An effort to port Drupal to Python [never really went anywhere](https://github.com/brendoncrawford/drupy).

Another interesting approach would be to run Drupal within [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), which would give you access to Drupal from Java; i.e. run PHP from within the JVM. I know that people have tried running Drupal in Quercus, but I'm not sure if they had any success. I don't know of an instance of Drupal/Quercus in production.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no magic to convert a PHP code intended to run as plugin for a PHP application to a Java web application.

What should be doable (with some work), is to run Drupal and the wanted module(s) in a Java Web Container using the [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) PHP engine. Quercus is a 100% Java implementation of PHP 5. So you wont convert anything but run PHP code on top of the Java platform (JVM, Web Container, etc.). The application code (Drupal core, module, themes, etc.) would be packaged as a .war file to be deployed on a Web Container.